# Migrate back to Ubuntu

Tags: lubuntu

I wanna migrate back from Lubuntu to Ubuntu but i dont want to lose my installed apps and all the other data and settings.
is this somehow possible???

thank you

---

Robert

Answer (score 1):

You can install `ubuntu-desktop` by running

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

and you will have choice to log into Ubuntu or Lubuntu.

It looks like the easiest way to do it.

Another alternative is to install Ubuntu over Lubuntu. It is possible to keep your user files, but you will have to re-install all applications.

Comment: Thank you. I think i choose the install ubuntu-desktop. dont want to reinstall all apps.

Answer (score 0):

@Pilot6's answer was only part of the solution for me when switching a recent install of lubuntu 23.10 to ubuntu. It successfully installed, but didn't change my login screen or give me an option to boot into gnome-shell (the ubuntu default desktop environment).

I needed to explicitly install gnome-shell:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

*(Maybe only `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` is required.)*

During this install, you will be prompted to select between `gdm3` and `sddm`. Choose **`gdm3`** because that's the Display Manager for GNOME.

I also removed lubuntu's default packages:

```
# Quick step and also prints lots of packages you no longer need.
sudo apt-get remove lubuntu-desktop
# Longer step to removes those unnecessary packages and frees up disk space.
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

After reboot, I had the ubuntu login screen and when I logged in I was using Gnome Shell. I still have some kde apps (QTerminal) but I'm still figuring out how I can easily clean that all up.